# How to show error message below the Input fields

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-aui

In my custom portlet, I want to show error message below the input fields,currently it showing above the input fields. I am using LR6.1.10EE ga1. I have done an analysis on this, under the server `\ROOT\html\js\aui\aui-form-validator\aui-form-validator.js` file handling the validation.

The javascript method `_defErrorFieldFn` defines the position where the error message is displayed by calling `field.placeBefore(stackContainer); // or field.placeAfter(stackContainer);`. By default `_defErrorFieldFn` calls `field.placeBefore(stackContainer);`.

Can anyone help me to override this in a custom portlet or find another solution? I don't want to change the core AlloyUI.

Comment: I think it is a CSS change, rather than JavaScript. Have you considered modifying your CSS to position error message below?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from the [`aui-form-validator` source](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/1.5.1/src/aui-form-validator/js/aui-form-validator.js)*, there does not seem to be a simple way to change the position of the error message via the API. I also tried overriding [`_defErrorFieldFn()`](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/1.5.1/src/aui-form-validator/js/aui-form-validator.js#L640) and changing `placeBefore()` to `placeAfter()`, but that did not work.

However, I did find a workaround which seems relatively elegant. [`_defErrorFieldFn()`](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/1.5.1/src/aui-form-validator/js/aui-form-validator.js#L640) calls [`printStackError()`](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/1.5.1/src/aui-form-validator/js/aui-form-validator.js#L475), which can be overridden to call `field.placeAfter(container)` before calling through to the original `printStackError()` like so:

```
formValidator.printStackErrorDefault = formValidator.printStackError;

formValidator.printStackError = function(field, container, errors) {
    field.placeAfter(container)
    formValidator.printStackErrorDefault(field, container, errors);
};
```

Here's a runnable example which shows this working:

```js
AUI().use('aui-form-validator', function (A) {
    formValidator = new A.FormValidator({
        boundingBox: '#myForm'
    });

    formValidator.printStackErrorBefore = formValidator.printStackError;

    formValidator.printStackError = function(field, container, errors) {
        field.placeAfter(container)
  formValidator.printStackErrorBefore(field, container, errors);
 };
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/1.5.1/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/1.5.1/aui-skin-classic/css/aui-skin-classic-all-min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<form id="myForm">
  <p>
    <label class="aui-field-label" for="name">Name:</label>
    <input class="aui-field-required" type="text" name="name" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label class="aui-field-label" for="email">Email:</label>
    <input class="aui-field-required aui-field-email" type="text" name="email" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label class="aui-field-label" for="age">Age:</label>
    <input class="aui-field-required aui-field-digits" type="text" name="age" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="aui-button-input" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input class="aui-button-input" type="reset" value="Reset" />
  </p>
</form>
```

*[Liferay 6.1 uses the AlloyUI 1.5 `aui-form-validator`](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/wiki/Liferay-Integration)